# Jquery use value of for loop to append to id attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making quiz like app. For every question, it will have 4 answers. Then I will use radio buttons to indicate the right answer.
How can I append the value of the loop to the id attribute?

Thank youuu

Here is my code snippet:

```
  $('#num_qu').on('change', function(){
    var num_of_qu = $('#num_qu').val();
    var html = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < num_of_qu; i++){
        html+= '<div class="row"><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
       <label>Name of question</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qu_name" 
         required></div></div></div>';
        for (j = 1; j < 5; j++){//4 answers
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id=answer_j placeholder="Answer" 
                        required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        }    
    }
```

Comment: So are both `for` loops to be added to `html`? I don't understand what's supposed to happen. As it stands the second `for` loop (with `j`) is doing nothing

Comment: @RolvApneseth Basically, I want the id to be like answer_1, answer_2

Comment: Sure, but you want the second loop to also be added to the html right? Currently it does nothing? And so there will be 1 label to 4 text inputs, is that what you want?

Comment: @RolvApneseth, I have not formatted it correctly yet. U r right. It should be like the first html

Comment: Ok, and you want it to be 1 label for 4 text inputs?

Comment: It has one question that is one input field. Each question will have 4 answers with 4 radio buttons to select the correct one

Comment: The inputs you have in the second loop are of `type='text'` do you want them to be radio buttons instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231817/discussion-between-alpha-and-rolv-apneseth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion, this answer works out for your needs:

```
$("#num_qu").on("change", function () {
  var num_of_qu = $("#num_qu").val();
  var html = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < num_of_qu; i++) {
    html += `<div class="row"><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
       <label>Name of question</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qu_name" 
         required></div></div></div>`;

    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
      //4 questions
      html += `<div class="row">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id=answer_${j} placeholder="Answer" 
                        required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
    }
  }
});
```

I just use template strings to place the value of j at the id attribute of the text input.